# Android Intent Redirection Vulnerability on my React Native app

Tags: react-native, android-security

Im 'new' developing in react-native. I uploaded a new version of my app, and i recieved an email from android saying that i have an intent redirection vuln on my app. But i dont know what is producing it. Can you help me to find it and fix it?
(I upgraded all my npm packages and the error was the same)
Thanks

Comment: It seems you might working with external app intents that can collect the user data from your application

please check out the official docs for more understanding 
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

please check your 3rd party libraries. in my case, the problem is in react native intercom

Comment: How do you discover that intercom was the library that caused the problem? I updated all my libraries and the problem continues

Comment: https://github.com/tinycreative/react-native-intercom/issues/415